# PHP base_url returning site, append variable strings to it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use PHP to generate a URL, from a database.

This is the script so far: (snippet)

```
$data['url'] = site_url('/'.$row['pid']);
```

That shows `http://www.domain.com/index.php/pid-variable-from-SQL`

I'm trying to use `base_url` to return the same URL except without the `index.php` part. It works, except chops off the `/pid-stuff` part.

Any help? Or why does this code not work?

```
$data['url'] = base_url('/'.$row['pid']);
```

Comment: DUDE, please read our FAQ, how many times have you created questions now that have been closed or moved, just read the FAQ and look around the site first.

Comment: Are you using a framework, or are the above functions custom ones? Because `site_url` and `base_url` are not part of the core PHP functions, as far as I know.

Comment: This makes no sense without seeing what `site_url` and `base_url` do

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. base/site_url is from codeignitor, and it's run through PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex to pluck out the index.php part of the URL.

```
$data['url'] = preg_replace("/(^http:\/\/.*?)\/(.*?)(\/.*)/", '$1$3', site_url('/'.$row['pid'])); //Should return http://www.domain.com/pid-variable-from-SQL
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked first time through, I just discarded the part before the = sign since I had a variable already set to use it.